# How can I save selected scope button in UISearchBar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar with 4 scope buttons. I need to store pressed scope button in the next time when user select another one, in objective C. Any ideas please?

SOLVED:
Here is the solution for other people

```
static NSString *yourKey = @"savedScopeSelection";
```

viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

NSInteger newIndex = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:yourKey];
[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setSelectedScopeButtonIndex:newIndex];

}
```

UISearchBar scope

```
    - (void)searchForText:(NSString *)searchText scope:(UYLWorldFactsSearchScope)scopeOption
{

    if (self.managedObjectContext)
    {

        NSString *predicateFormat = @"%K contains[cd] %@";
        NSString *searchAttribute = @"option0";
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:0 forKey:yourKey];
        if (scopeOption == searchScopeOption1)

        {
            searchAttribute = @"option1";
             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:1 forKey:yourKey];
        }

        if (scopeOption == searchScopeOption2)
        {
            searchAttribute = @"option2";
             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:2 forKey:yourKey];
        }

        if (scopeOption == searchScopeOption3)
        {
            searchAttribute = @"option3";
             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:3 forKey:yourKey];
        }

        if (scopeOption == searchScopeOption4)
        {
            searchAttribute = @"option4";
             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:4 forKey:yourKey];

        }

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateFormat, searchAttribute, searchText];
        [self.searchFetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

        NSError *error = nil;
        self.filteredList = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:self.searchFetchRequest error:&error];
        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"searchFetchRequest failed: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a good time to use NSUserDefaults.

set up a static key somewhere

```
static NSString *yourKey = @"savedScopeSelection";
```

when you make a selection, store the value of the index you selected:

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:newIndexValue forKey:yourKey];
```

when you initialize the search bar, look in defaults to get the stored index:

```
  NSInteger *newIndex = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:yourKey];
```

I would recommend that you have each of the scope buttons represented by an integer. You could use an enum like this:

```
enum ScopeButtonIndex: Int {
    case thisScope = 1
    case thatScope = 2
    case otherScope = 3
    case fourthScope = 4
}
```

I like to specifically give it an index because I'm storing it in the userDefaults, and I don't want to accidentally change the index values by adding another value in some future version